# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Nathan Osman]
[image: Ed Cottrell]
[image: Jason Down]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congratulations! (or condolences?) to new mods!

Comment: I have absolutely no objection to Ed's inclusion.  But he was not on the nomination question so I am just wondering how he was selected?

Comment: @Chad: Good question.  I started to compile a list of people I thought would make good moderators right from the start of the private beta.  Some of them were nominated, but Ed wasn't.  I think of moderators as a team that needs a combination of domain knowledge, SE network knowledge, and mediation ability.  If we limit ourselves to the nominations, we risk having an unbalanced team.  (That said, the nominations was an important data point for me.)